# how to hide odoo 13 point of sale kanban droplist/drop menu?

Tags: odoo, add-on, odoo-13

I tried this code but nothing happened:

#view.xml

```
<odoo>
 <data>

  <record id="view_pos_config_kanban_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">pos.config.inherit</field>
    <field name="model">pos.config</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="point_of_sale.view_pos_config_kanban"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
     <xpath expr="//kanban/templates/t/div/div[3][contains(@class='o_kanban_manage_button_section')]" position="replace">
     </xpath>
    </field>
  </record>

 </data>
</odoo>
```

[What I want To Hide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBr3d.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Solution:

```
<odoo>
    <data>
        <record id="view_pos_config_kanban" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">pos.config.kanban.view</field>
            <field name="model">pos.config</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="point_of_sale.view_pos_config_kanban"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <xpath expr="//kanban/templates/t/div/div[1]/div[2][@class='o_kanban_manage_button_section']" position="replace">
                </xpath>
            </field>
        </record>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

Comment: This kind of XPATH is very risky It will break by other xpath that addes div, when I target a div that don't have a name or a special class I target a special child inside then go up to it, `//field[@name='dummy']/parent::div` and you can keep going up as much as you want as i remember, bottom line avoid using index of element as much as possible

Comment: And onething more dont use `@class='value'` instead use `hasclass('value')` because class can change a lot especially in website templates by other modules

Answer (score 1):

Odoo will raise `odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: "Invalid number of arguments"` because of `contains` function used in `div`.

You can check in the [XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) documentation provided by Odoo that `contains` is a function to manipulate strings:

```
contains(s1, s2)
    returns true if s1 contains s2
```

Use `XPath` to locate the `div` with `o_kanban_manage_button_section` class and make it invisible.

***Example:***

```
<record id="view_pos_config_kanban" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">pos.config.kanban.view</field>
    <field name="model">pos.config</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="point_of_sale.view_pos_config_kanban"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//t/div/div/div[@class='o_kanban_manage_button_section']" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="invisible">True</attribute>
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer , it give me hint to solution , i was wrongly located the div i want